# How to auto-translate other-languages fiels using django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-models, django-modeltranslation

**Is there any way in which the other-languages fields can be auto-translated**

[image]

*Like in this picture I want to auto-translate the Name[pt] , Body[pt] fields by seeing the (en)-fields.*

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use third party service for auto translation. You can use https://www.transifex.com. Call the transfix api when inserting data into your model.